# Valid regex not working in python

Tags: python, regex

I have following regex that seem to be working fine on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zU6kG0/1).
As you can see my four possible combinations are matched.

Now if I want to implement this in python, I get no match at all when I try to match a line similar to the first line in regex101 string field (line with nothing after the network address). Here is the code

```
import re 

l_side = 'ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 40 permit 192.168.10.0/23'

myregex = re.compile(r'''
(ip\sprefix-list)\s
(?P<prefnam>\w+)\s
(?P<prefseq>seq\s\d+)\s
(permit|deny)\s
(?P<prefnet>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[1-3]?\d)\s
((?P<prefgele>ge\s\d{1,2}\sle\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefge>ge\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefle>le\s\d{1,2})|)
''', re.VERBOSE)
l_match = myregex.search(l_side)

print(l_match.group('prefnam'))
print(l_match.group('prefgele'))
```

Here is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testing.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(l_match.group('prefnam'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

if I remove the folowing from the regex

```
((?P<prefgele>ge\s\d{1,2}\sle\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefge>ge\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefle>le\s\d{1,2})|)
```

then it works.

All I am trying to match here is existance of `gele` or `le` or `ge` or nothing. I have also tried the following with no luck.

```
((?P<prefgele>ge\s\d{1,2}\sle\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefge>ge\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefle>le\s\d{1,2})|(.?))
```

Any idea on what is going on here

## EDIT1:

After Samuel answer I have tested but it seem that all case are not matched

1. ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 10 permit 192.168.1.80/28
2. ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 20 permit 192.168.1.80/28 ge 23 le 25
3. ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 30 permit 192.168.1.80/28 ge 23
4. ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 40 permit 192.168.1.80/28 le 23

1 and 2 are matched but not 3 and 4

I have amended Samuel regex to:

```
(ip\sprefix-list)\s
(?P<prefnam>\w+)\s
(?P<prefseq>seq\s\d+)\s
(permit|deny)\s
(?P<prefnet>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/[1-3])?\d)
((\s(?P<prefgele>ge\s\d{1,2}\sle\s\d{1,2}))|
(\s(?P<prefge>ge\s\d{1,2}))|
(\s(?P<prefle>le\s\d{1,2})))?
```

It seem to match all case now. Thanks Sam.

Comment: I have already been down voted, I wonder what's wrong with my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And with this regex?

```
import re 

l_side = 'ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 40 permit 192.168.10.0/23'

myregex = re.compile(r'''
(ip\sprefix-list)\s
(?P<prefnam>\w+)\s
(?P<prefseq>seq\s\d+)\s
(permit|deny)\s
(?P<prefnet>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/[1-3])?\d)(\s
(?P<prefgele>ge\s\d{1,2}\sle\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefge>ge\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefle>le\s\d{1,2})|)?
''', re.VERBOSE)
l_match = myregex.search(l_side)

print(l_match.group('prefnam'))
#print(l_match.group('prefgele'))
```

the diff is for

```
(?P<prefnet>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[1-3]?\d)
```

replaced by

```
(?P<prefnet>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/[1-3])?\d)
```

and after i replace

```
\s
((?P<prefgele>ge\s\d{1,2}\sle\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefge>ge\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefle>le\s\d{1,2})|)
```

by

```
(\s
(?P<prefgele>ge\s\d{1,2}\sle\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefge>ge\s\d{1,2})|
(?P<prefle>le\s\d{1,2})|)?
```

Comment: Good catch!.  This is a common shortcoming in online testers like Regex101: you can't make them treat each line as if it were a standalone string, with no linefeed at the end.  By the way, that last `|` is redundant now that the enclosing group is optional.

Comment: Merci Samuel. It seem to be working fine for when `ge XX le XX` but when `ge XX` or `le XX` it doesnt capture the corresponding group. Also I understand the change you have made to the end of the regex but I don't get the `prefnet` bit where you say "the diff is for your". Can you expend on your explanation?

Comment: Fixed now working but I don't get the prefnet bit where you say "the diff is for your". Can you expend on your explanation?

Comment: Sry it's simply because i was tired, and i have made a typing error.